# Cardinality of arithmetic sequences

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $S$ be the set of arithmetic sequences $(a_n)_n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, i.e. there exists $d\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}: a_{n+1} -a_n=d$.

> What is the cardinality of $S$?

I thought about it as all the functions from $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$, so that gives ${\aleph _0}^    {\aleph _ 0} $.

The answer was the same but the conclusion was due to the face that you can choose $a_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $d\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Is my conclusion is right?

Answer (score 3):

No, not quite.

Arithmetic sequences are determined by the difference $d$ of two subsequent terms and the initial value $a_0$. That is, there is a bijection  $$S\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$$
$$(a_n)_n\longmapsto (d,a_0)$$
The inverse map is given by $a_n=a_0+n\cdot d$.

Therefore the cardinality is

$$|S|=|\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}|=|\mathbb{Z}|=\aleph_0$$

This is strictly smaller than $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}=|\mathbb{R}|$.

Comment: But a sequences is a function isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is but your set includes only a very small subset of the set of all sequences (i.e. of all functions $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: A sequence is a function $\Bbb N \to \Bbb Z$, correct.  But the fact that it is an arithmetic progression picks out just a few of the functions.